# how to check whether null value is present in an array.if present how can we assign "NULL" at that place?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this...

```
  $myArray = array('id' => '144', 'category' =>'21', 'rating' => '');
```

i need to get the result as

```
  $myArray = array('id' => '144', 'category' =>'21', 'rating' => 'NULL');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $array = array_map(function($val) {
       return $val === "" ? NULL : $val;
    }, $a)
```